# Get multiple results for PL/SQL decalred variable from scala

Tags: oracle, scala, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a PL/SQL procedure like below.

```
Create or replace procedure SP 
AS 
a Varchar(18);
B NUMBER;
CURSOR c_one IS
 ( SOME SELECT QUERY);

CURSOR c_two IS
 ( SOME SELECT QUERY);
BEGIN
  OPEN c_one;
    --SOME STUFF;
  CLOSE cursor;

    LOOP
    OPEN c_two;
    --SOME STUFF;
    CLOSE cursor;

   dbms_output.put_line(a)

    END LOOP;

END
```

I need to call this SP in my scala code and get all the values of `a` . So I execute the SP in my code as below.

`val callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{CALL SP}")`

What should I do next to get the all results of `a`?

Comment: Which scala library you use for sql?

Comment: Your stored procedure uses DBMS_OUTPUT which displays to the screen but doesn't return anything. You need to rewrite your procedure so it returns a Ref Cursor as an OUT parameter. Then you can call the procedure from Scala mapping the parameter to a JDBC ResultSet. [Find out more](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets).

Comment: You could make a OUT parameter for example: r_one OUT TableA%ROWTYPE. And fetch c_one into r_one.

Comment: @IvaKam It's `mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "8.0.12`

Comment: @APC Thanks for the answer. I'll try it

Comment: @Tenzin I did that one also to get all the values of `a` . But it gave me only one value of `a` as result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem editing the stored procedure.

```
Create or replace procedure SP ( out_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS 

ID Varchar(18);
Emp_Name Varchar(18);

CURSOR c_one IS
 ( SOME SELECT QUERY);

CURSOR c_two IS
 ( SOME SELECT QUERY);

BEGIN

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE tempTable';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE tempTable(Emp_ID VARCHAR(50)) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS';

  OPEN c_one;
    --SOME STUFF;
  CLOSE cursor;

    LOOP
    OPEN c_two;
    --SOME STUFF;
    CLOSE cursor;

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO tempTable(Emp_ID) VALUES('||ID||')';

   END LOOP;

   OPEN out_cursor FOR 'SELECT * FROM tempTable';

END;
```

Then I called to the SP in my scala code and created a dataframe using result set.

```
var lst:List[String] = List[String]()

try{
  val callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{CALL SP(?)}")
  callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR)
  callableStatement.execute()

  val rs = callableStatement.getObject(1).asInstanceOf[ResultSet]

  while (rs.next()){
     val i = rs.getString(1)
     lst ::=i
    }

 val ds = lst.toDS().toDF("EMP_ID")

 //rest of the code

}catch {
      case e: Exception => e.printStackTrace
    }
```